# How to print all values in character array in C

Tags: c++, arrays, char, cout

Could you please help me why this code is not printing the char array of '*' chars as expected?

```
int n = 10;
char *cs = (char*) calloc(n + 1, sizeof(char));
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cs[i] = '*';
}
cout << cs << endl;
```

Googled around a lot, but didn't find the same problem anywhere..

Thanks!

Comment: I doesn't reproduce if I complete the code in the obvious (at least for me) way. Please give the full code.

Comment: @H2CO3 The terminating zero is there because of `calloc`.

Comment: `calloc()` should have done this. @H2CO3

Comment: This works like a charm, take a look: [link to ideone](http://ideone.com/FhGHoF).

Comment: code is running fine http://ideone.com/49GA6P

Comment: Does it compile? @user1815036

Comment: Here's the complete code:
`int main() {
 int n;
 do {
  cout << "Give me a natural number:" << endl;
  cin >> n;
 } while (n < 1);
 char *cs = (char*) calloc(n+1, sizeof(char));
 for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
  cs[i] = '*';
 }
 cout << cs << endl;
 return 0;
}`

Now that is weird..
Because as soon as i switched from Debug to Run it started working perfectly.
Using Eclipse as IDE, maybe there went something wrong?!

Comment: Anyway, big thanks for your quick help!!
It seems Eclipse was the cause of this..

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Ah, right, it's strange that someone uses these properly... :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written the same code in the studio and for me its working fine. Giving `*` as output.

```
int main()
{
    int n=10;
    char *cs = (char*) calloc(n+1, sizeof(char));
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        cs[i] = '*';
    }
    cout << cs << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yep, now it's OK. Eclipse worked strangely for me somehow.. Thanks!